# Does maven run JUnit tests sequentially?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a multi module **Maven** project. In one module I've got a few unit tests that start an **HTTP server**. Sometimes I got errors because a server cannot be started on a port because it is already occupied. This does not seem correct if maven runs tests sequentially.

Comment: If you need a specified order you should use TestNG instead and by definition a unit test does not have a specified order which means your tests are integration tests...and should be handled by maven-failsafe-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

By design, unit tests should be independent and not run sequentially.  Therefore, JUnit and the maven test task, do not run them sequentially by default. As of JUnit 4.11, it now supports specifying execution order using [@FixMethodOrder](http://junit.org/apidocs/index.html?org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html) annoation. If you are looking to test functionality outside of a given unit of code, however, then you should consider integration testing.

This can be achieved a couple of different ways.  If you need to test content within a container, you can use [Arquilion](http://arquillian.org/).  You may also mock the functionality of dependent objects using mocking libraries like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).